# Slick Prepared Statement

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, hikaricp

I'm using slick 3.0.0-M1 with "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.4.3"

**Slick is preparing a statement for every query (indicated by logging) which is bad:**

```
"Preparing statement: select * from ..."
```

**My configuration tells Slick / Hikari to cache prepared statements:**

```
myDB {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://...
  user = ...
  ...
  connectionPool = HikariCP
  queueSize = 50000
  maxConnections = 50
  properties.cachePrepStmts = true
  properties.prepStmtCacheSize = 20000
  properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit = 100000
}
```

**The logs seem to indicate these properties are read:**

```
configuration:
...
dataSourceName..................
dataSourceClassName.............
dataSourceProperties............
    {password=<masked>, 
     prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=100000, 
     cachePrepStmts=true, 
     prepStmtCacheSize=20000}
maximumPoolSize.................50
poolName..........................
```

**The db object is instantiated and used in a test:**

```
val db = Database.forConfig("", config.getConfig("myDB"))
val qTemplate = StaticQuery[(Int), MyRow] + "select * from table_name where num=?"
db.withSession{ implicit session =>
   (0 until 100).foreach{ case i => 
       qTemplate(2).foreach(println)
   } 
}
```

For every call to qTemplate(2), slick logs 'Preparing Statement...' Why is the template not cached?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you use a production version of Slick like 3.1.1 if you'd like the latest. http://slick.typesafe.com/

Normally, the connection pool does connection caching and the database does statement caching. Using a PreparedStatement with placeholders like ? should be sufficient for MySql to cache the statement. The database must parse the statement and each statement must look the same for the DB to cache the statement. Having the database avoid parsing the same statement over and over with different parameter values is what this feature avoids.

If you look at the document about statement caching will also help explain - https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP - There is some more information about MySQL here as well - https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration

I would just upgrade Slick and continue doing what you are doing.

Eric

Comment: The Documentation says that Slick uses prepared statements wherever possible but it does not cache them on its own. You should therefore enable prepared statement caching in the connection pool’s configuration.

Comment: I see what you are referring to here - http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/database.html - Someone from the Slick team may have to clarify. Slick generates SQL if you do not use direct SQL so they may be referring to Slick generated SQL. The way I understand it the SQL and the params are passed to the DB via the driver. Then the DB can look up the already parsed statement and using the param data execute the statement without parsing the statement.

Comment: I investigated more, and it seems like those parameterized statements are working.